# IK only moving the last bone of the chain

Tags: inverse-kinematics

I have this skeleton for a cow :

[image: cow skeleton]

With this property for both IK bones :

[image: ik properties]

The problem that I have is that when moving the front leg, the bone directly connected to my bone with IK constraints will not rotate. The angle will stay exactly the same. If I increase the chain length, then they will all be stiff joints, only the last joint will rotate. You can see what I mean in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMw19OFTO_g).
The backleg works perfectly fine. I already deleted it all and restarted but I have the same issue.

[EDIT] Here is the file : [image]

Comment: hello could you please share the armature? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots sure, I have edited the post with it. https://blend-exchange.com/b/Od4JjxP6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do the following steps:

Correctly align the bones with a <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Global +X Axis*:

[image]

Bend the knees a bit more so that it knows how it is supposed to bend them:

[image]

Put the head of the controller at the same location as the tail of the lowerleg, so that it doesn't jump as soon as you switch to *Pose* mode:

[image]

Correct the *Pole Angle*:

[image]

It should work:

[image]

Comment: Thank you that did it !  Even though when I enter 0° in the pool angle, the foot doesn't get in the right position on my side. Thank you !